# Error in loading drupal website

Tags: php, drupal

I'm a new Drupal user, I have already a website drupal file, I want to load it on localhost, after installing drupal, and when I want to access to localhost/mysite/index.php, I got this error:

> Access denied
>
> warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'ctools_access_menu' not found or invalid function
>   name in C:\wamp\www\mysite\includes\menu.inc on line 454.
>
> You are not authorized to access this page.

What should I do? And how can I import an existing drupal project on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module to backup your live site and then restore it on your localhost.

Comment: i didnt understood how to use it ! is it for importing an existing website files ?

Comment: Please follow these tutorials: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-backup-and-migrate and https://modulesunraveled.com/backup-and-migrate

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Copy all the files.
2. Copy database
3. Set correct new database credentials in `/sites/default/settings.php`
4. Make sure that you have same PHP libraries enabled at new website environment.
5. Make sure that you have appropriate PHP/MySql versions for your Drupal version
6. Make sure that Drupal can write all the paths it needs *Configuration -> Media -> File* system and hit Save (Drupal 7, similar should be for other versions) - problematic paths will become outlined in red.